# How can I setup an end to end ssl conection with application gateway and apache httpd?

Tags: apache, azure, azure-application-gateway

I am setting, on Azure, an application gateway that I want to have an end to end SSL connection with my apache httpd server that servers my page from a vm

I have set Listener and HTTP setting, it seems to work with simple http for frontend and backend

My server serves https with a ".crt" certificate

In order for the end to end https to work on application gateway, you need to whitelist the back end certificate. In order to do that you need to add a ".cer" file in an HTTP setting.

When I request the page I get the following error:

`502 Bad Gateway
Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2`

Already I followed the following guides provided by Microsoft

- https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/azure/application-gateway/end-to-end-ssl-portal
- https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502#problems-with-default-health-probe

As mentioned in the first reference, the FQDN of the backend pool should be the same as the CN of the certificate.

Also, I tried to generate a ".pfx" and then export the ".cer" and ".crt" files without any luck.

The backend health probe returns that the backend server is healthy
so the appgateway can reach the backend host.
I am using V2 and add the base 64 encoded ".cer"
The FQDN is the same as the dns name of the backend node

I used the following commands in order to generate the certificates

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 \
-days 1024 -out rootCA.crt

openssl genrsa -out my.domain.com.key 2048


openssl req -new -sha256 -key my.domain.com.key \
-subj "/C=GR/ST=Attica/O=mycompany/CN=my.domain.com" \
 -out my.domain.com.csr


openssl x509 -req -in my.domain.com.csr \
-CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial \
-out my.domain.com.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

After that I imported the "rootCA.crt" file to windows certification manager and exported as a base64 ".cer"
I used the exported certificate in the Trusted Root Certificates section in application gateway

The deployment template is the following:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name": {
            "defaultValue": "name-app-gateway",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_name_app_gateway_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/[subscription-id]/resourceGroups/name-app-gateway-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/name-app-gateway",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "publicIPAddresses_name_app_gateway_pip_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/[subscription-id]/resourceGroups/name-app-gateway-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/name-app-gateway-pip",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')]",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "properties": {
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "resourceGuid": "20beed4d-2ff5-440b-918f-5772d6c91ad2",
                "sku": {
                    "name": "Standard_v2",
                    "tier": "Standard_v2"
                },
                "gatewayIPConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "appGatewayIpConfig",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_name_app_gateway_externalid'), '/subnets/default')]"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/gatewayIPConfigurations"
                    }
                ],
                "sslCertificates": [
                    {
                        "name": "company",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "publicCertData": "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"
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/sslCertificates"
                    }
                ],
                "trustedRootCertificates": [
                    {
                        "name": "server-uat",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "data": "sertificate data"
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/trustedRootCertificates"
                    }
                ],
                "frontendIPConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "appGwPublicFrontendIp",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                            "publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[parameters('publicIPAddresses_name_app_gateway_pip_externalid')]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "frontendPorts": [
                    {
                        "name": "port_443",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "port": 443
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendPorts"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "http-port",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "port": 80
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendPorts"
                    }
                ],
                "backendAddressPools": [
                    {
                        "name": "server",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "backendAddresses": [
                                {
                                    "fqdn": "server-prod.internal.company.com"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendAddressPools"
                    }
                ],
                "backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
                    {
                        "name": "server-http-setting",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "port": 443,
                            "protocol": "Https",
                            "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
                            "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": true,
                            "requestTimeout": 20,
                            "trustedRootCertificates": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/trustedRootCertificates/server')]"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/trustedRootCertificates/httpd')]"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/trustedRootCertificates/server-http-settingeeab8427-4514-4ef4-8e94-7d155a76f037')]"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/trustedRootCertificates/httpd-root')]"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/trustedRootCertificates/server-uat')]"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "server-http-80-setting",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "port": 80,
                            "protocol": "Http",
                            "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
                            "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": false,
                            "affinityCookieName": "ApplicationGatewayAffinity",
                            "requestTimeout": 20
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection"
                    }
                ],
                "httpListeners": [
                    {
                        "name": "server-l",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/frontendIPConfigurations/appGwPublicFrontendIp')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/frontendPorts/port_443')]"
                            },
                            "protocol": "Https",
                            "sslCertificate": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/sslCertificates/company')]"
                            },
                            "requireServerNameIndication": false
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "server-http-l",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/frontendIPConfigurations/appGwPublicFrontendIp')]"
                            },
                            "frontendPort": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/frontendPorts/http-port')]"
                            },
                            "protocol": "Http",
                            "requireServerNameIndication": false
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/httpListeners"
                    }
                ],
                "urlPathMaps": [],
                "requestRoutingRules": [
                    {
                        "name": "server-rr",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "ruleType": "Basic",
                            "httpListener": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/httpListeners/server-l')]"
                            },
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/backendAddressPools/server')]"
                            },
                            "backendHttpSettings": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/backendHttpSettingsCollection/server-http-setting')]"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/requestRoutingRules"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "redirect-to-https",
                        "etag": "W/\"be033d5e-9b23-400a-b6ca-f5cbede2a4e5\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "ruleType": "Basic",
                            "httpListener": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/httpListeners/server-http-l')]"
                            },
                            "backendAddressPool": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/backendAddressPools/server')]"
                            },
                            "backendHttpSettings": {
                                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways', parameters('serverapplicationGateways_name_app_gateway_name')), '/backendHttpSettingsCollection/server-http-80-setting')]"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/requestRoutingRules"
                    }
                ],
                "probes": [],
                "rewriteRuleSets": [],
                "redirectConfigurations": [],
                "enableHttp2": false,
                "autoscaleConfiguration": {
                    "minCapacity": 2,
                    "maxCapacity": 10
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could check the `backend health` in the monitoring of the application gateway. Find the error details about the 502 error then troubleshoot it following the steps-by-steps from [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4504111/azure-application-gateway-with-bad-gateway-502-errors). Perhaps, you could also narrow down the scenario if this works when you set the normal settings with the HTTP protocol.

Authentication Certificates have been deprecated and replaced by **Trusted Root Certificates** in the Application Gateway **v2** SKU. It seems that you need to ensure you are using a root cert for whitelisting the backends in the **HTTP settings**.

For the V2 SKU, you should note the followings reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview#end-to-end-ssl-with-the-v2-sku).

> - Certificates signed by well known CA authorities whose CN matches the host name in the HTTP backend settings do not require any
>     additional step for end to end SSL to work.
> - For example, if the backend certificates are issued by a well known CA and has a CN of contoso.com, and the backend http setting’s host
>     field is also set to contoso.com, then no additional steps are
>     required. You can set the backend http setting protocol to HTTPS and
>     both the health probe and data path would be SSL enabled. If you're
>     using Azure App Service or other Azure web services as your backend,
>     then these are implicitly trusted as well and no further steps are
>     required for end to end SSL.
> - If the certificate is self-signed, or signed by unknown intermediaries, then to enable end to end SSL in v2 SKU a trusted root
>     certificate must be defined. Application Gateway will only communicate
>     with backends whose Server certificate’s root certificate matches one
>     of the list of trusted root certificates in the backend http setting
>     associated with the pool.
> - In addition to root certificate match, Application Gateway also validates if the Host setting specified in the backend http setting
>     matches that of the common name (CN) presented by the backend server’s
>     SSL certificate. When trying to establish an SSL connection to the
>     backend, Application Gateway sets the Server Name Indication (SNI)
>     extension to the Host specified in the backend http setting.
> - If **pick hostname from backend addres**s is chosen instead of the **Host** field in the backend http setting, then the SNI header is always
>     set to the backend pool FQDN and **the CN on the backend server SSL
>     certificate must match its FQDN**. Backend pool members with IPs aren't
>     supported in this scenario.
> - The root certificate is a base64 encoded root certificate from the backend Server certificates.

If the above all is no effect, you could upload your settings with hiding some sensitive data for further help.

Comment: the health probe returns a healthy response which means that the application gateway can reach the backend pool

Comment: Does the health probe setting match the HTTP setting such as protocol,host, path? Do you any NSG in your app gateway subnet?

Comment: the app gateway subnet does not have any NSG, the host and the gateway are not in the same subnet but the connection is allowed

Comment: Does the health probe match the HTTP setting using protocol https?

Comment: I have two health probs, https and https, and they are healthy

Comment: Do you have any custom FQDN of app GW? Do you get the 502 error when you access the app gateway? and it fails on all requests or a few of them?

Comment: I have added an FQDN on app gateway but I get the same error while I try to access it with its public IP
The error is consistent

Comment: Is there a way to trace the call in the application gateway?

Comment: You need to provide `my.domain.com` as host name in the backend http setting. i.e. host name must match the subject name/SAN of the cert. otherwise, the certificate validation fails.

Comment: From your template, it seems that you do not add the health probe? You should follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview) to add it then you can monitor the app GW in backend health. You also could enable the [diagnostic log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics) for troubleshooting the app gw issue.

Comment: Once you have a backend pool you can check its health using the default health probe, you can over right it with a custom one if you want to check something more specific. I tried both and the were resulting to a healthy response

Comment: Do you have a public domain or custom private domain? If you have a public domain, i'd like to suggest creating a .cer or .pfx cert from your trusted CA.

Comment: The domain is private, I the purpose is to have SSL e2e, I will add a certificate from trusted CA in the frontend part of the application gateway